# the map $f:[0,1]\to [a,b]$ $f(x,y)=(1-x)a+xb$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: continuity

A question I just came across :
     A bijection $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous .
Show that the map $f:[0,1]\to [a,b]$  $$f(x)=(1-x)a+xb$$ is a homomorphism...

I don't know how to go with solving to show $f^{-1}$ is continuous..

Comment: I think you mean *homEomorphism*.  Maybe you should first find what $f^{-1}$ is.  Also, $f$ is a function of a single variable, so I think you mean $f(x)=(1-x)a+xb$.

Comment: @Hayden yes...I'm sorry about mistake ,I've made edit..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
f^{-1}(y) = x \iff f(x) = y \implies f^{-1}(a + x(b-a)) = x
$$
now put $y = a + x(b-a)$ to figure out how $f^{-1}$ maps $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply compute the inverse:

$$y=x(b-a)+a\to x=\frac{y-a}{b-a}$$

that is,

$$f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

that is clearly a continuous function.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can find explicit formula for $f^{-1}$:

$$y=(1-x)a+xb=a+x(b-a)$$

So for $a \neq b$:

$$x=\frac{y-a}{b-a}$$

You can check that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ (for example by checking $f(f^{-1}(x))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$).